# How to read data from multiple Firestore collections at the same time?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

My home screen contains different kinds of data: slideshow, popular products, discount products, featured brands, nearby shops, ... which are stored in different Firestore collections (some are in the same collection but different queries).

If we develop with Web API, we can respond to those data to a single endpoint request.

Rather than loading those data separately in Firestore, do we have another option that can load from a single task just like we do with Web API?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Firebase Client SDKs? If yes, then you'll have to make a different request for each collection. You can just use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run them simultaneously in a function.

Even if you write an API endpoint on your server to get everything in a single response, you'll be making different requests for each collection just using the server side SDKs.